# auth0, getting Schema error at securityDefinitions.auth0

Tags: swagger, auth0

i get this error on swagger editor when using the auth0

```
Schema error at securityDefinitions.auth0
is not exactly one from <#/definitions/basicAuthenticationSecurity>,<#/definitions/apiKeySecurity>,<#/definitions/oauth2ImplicitSecurity>,<#/definitions/oauth2PasswordSecurity>,<#/definitions/oauth2ApplicationSecurity>,<#/definitions/oauth2AccessCodeSecurity>
Jump to line 67
```

where my .yaml file is like:

```
securityDefinitions:
  auth0:
    type: oauth2
    authorizationUrl: https://domain.auth0.com/authorize
    flow: implicit
    tokenName: id_token
    scopes:
      openid: Grant access to user
  apiKey:
    type: apiKey
    name: api-key
    in: query
  apiKey1:
    type: apiKey
    name: api-key
    in: header
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tokenName` - it's not a supported field.

Check the specification to see which fields are allowed in `securityDefinitions`:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securitySchemeObject

Comment: Hi, this did not work as I got `{
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": "UnauthorizedError",
      "message": "jwt malformed",
      "code": "invalid_token",
      "status": 401,
      "inner": {
        "name": "JsonWebTokenError",
        "message": "jwt malformed"
      }
    }
  ]
}` error

Comment: @khinester: That's an actual response from your API and it has nothing to do with the syntax error in your original question. You should [ask a new question](/questions/ask) about that.